# Extract by Mask tool not clipping to mask extent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, arcgis-10.4, extract-by-mask

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1.

I am using the Extract by Mask tool to clip a raster using a polygon shapefile. When the tool finishes running, the output raster does not fill the entire mask extent (see attached image). I have made sure that my raster and shapefile are using the same coordinate system.

Any idea what's going on?

[image]

Comment: Are your features multipolygons? Try to create new shapefile with a small square polygon and test again.

Comment: @Mr.Che I created a square polygon to use as the mask and the tool worked perfectly. Could there be a problem with my shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Clip tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm) to clip the raster data. You can find it from `ArcToolbox -> Data Management Tools -> Raster -> Raster Processing -> Clip`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using the clip tool with the box checked that you suggested, but the output raster still does not fill the entire mask extent.

Comment: If your polygon shapefile is multipolygon, you can split them by editing the shapefile. Use `Start editing from the editor toolbar -> select the polygon shapefile -> go advanced editing toolbar and select explode feature`, then save edits. After that select the polygon you want to use as clip feature and use the clip tool as explained in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be caused by (my guesses):

1. Incorrect vector geometry, check and repair it with the [Check Geometry tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm).
2. Singlepart nature of the features, try to use [Multipart To Singlepart tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm).
3. Multipart nature of the features, try to create single  file for every feature and try again (so you will get new raster for every polygon).